# Filename in a nested DO loop - Fortran

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran

I'm trying to write a variable filename that uses two integers. Initially, I had following which worked perfectly.

```
write(my_uni,"(a,i4.4,a)") "test_data",nrevs,".csv"
open(unit=11,file=my_uni,action='write',position='append')
```

But now I'm trying to do this which is giving me an error:

```
 write(my_uni,"(a,i4.4,a)") "test",nrevs,"data",myrank,".csv"
 open(unit=11,file=my_uni,action='write',position='append')
```

Can someone please help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to update the format.  Try `'(A,I4.4,A,I4.4,A)'`

Comment: Also when reporting an error please, please always tell us what the error is